# Nestjs Response Serialization with array of objects

Tags: node.js, typescript, serialization, nestjs, class-transformer

I want to serialize a controller response by the nestjs serialization technique. I didn't find any approach and my solution is as follows:

### User Entity

```
export type UserRoleType = "admin" | "editor" | "ghost";

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number;

    @Column('text')
        username: string;
    @Column('text') 
        password: string;
    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: ["admin", "editor", "ghost"],
        default: "ghost"
    })
    roles: UserRoleType;
        @Column({ nullable: true })
                profileId: number;  
}
```

### User Response Classes

```
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

export class UserResponse {
    id: number;

    username: string;

    @Exclude()
    roles: string;

    @Exclude()
    password: string;

    @Exclude()
    profileId: number;  

    constructor(partial: Partial<UserResponse>) {
        Object.assign(this, partial);
    }
}

import { Exclude, Type } from 'class-transformer';
import { User } from 'src/_entities/user.entity';
import { UserResponse } from './user.response';

export class UsersResponse {

    @Type(() => UserResponse)
    users: User[]   

    constructor() { }
}
```

### Controller

```
@Controller('user')
export class UsersController {
    constructor(
        private readonly userService: UserService
    ) {

    }
    @UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
    @Get('all')
    async findAll(
    ): Promise<UsersResponse> {
        let users = await this.userService.findAll().catch(e => { throw new   NotAcceptableException(e) })
        let rsp =new UsersResponse() 
        rsp.users = users
        return rsp
    }
```

It works, but I must explicitly assign the db query result to the response users member.
Is there a better way? Thanks a lot

Here the actual Response and wanted result, for a better explanation.

### Result in this Approach

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "a"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "bbbbbb"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Result Wanted

```
{
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "a"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "bbbbbb"
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343262/class-validator-validate-array-of-objects/58366367#58366367 should help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to directly put the `@Exclude` decorators on your entity class `User` instead of duplicating the properties in `UserResponse`. The following answer assumes you have done so.

---

### Flat Response

If you have a look at the code of the [`ClassSerializerInterceptor`](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/serializer/class-serializer.interceptor.ts), you can see that it automatically handles arrays:

```
return isArray
  ? (response as PlainLiteralObject[]).map(item =>
      this.transformToPlain(item, options),
    )
  : this.transformToPlain(response, options);
```

However, it will only transform them, if you directly return the array, so `return users` instead of `return {users: users}`:

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Get('all')
async findAll(): Promise<User> {
    return this.userService.findAll()
}
```

---

### Nested Response

If you need the nested response, then your way is a good solution.
Alternatively, you can call class-transformer's `serialize` directly instead of using the `ClassSerializerInterceptor`. It also handles arrays automatically:

```
import { serialize } from 'class-transformer';

@Get('all')
async findAll(): Promise<UsersResponse> {
  const users: User[] = await this.userService.findAll();
  return {users: serialize(users)};
}
```

Comment: Thanks so lot for your answer, that gives me more details and i edited my question with the wanted result.

Comment: Great, then you can just return the users array  directly from your controller `return users`. For that to work, don't forget to add the `@Exclude()` decorators directly to your `UserEntity` class. If this solves your problem, consider accepting an answer. Of course, you can also leave it open and wait for another answer. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: any reason of not recommending the duplicate dto(entity) for you db entity ? I'm designing new nestJs app with the same hierarchy mentioned by the OP in the question i.e. db entity -> db entity abstract dto(same exact fields with no decorators) -> request dto extending db entity dto(with validations decorators) -> response dto expending db entity dto(transformation decorators). Just curious to understand why you recommend to use entities for response rather a separate dto.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is recommended by nestjs but that has a fault. You are excluding some properties from being exposed to the client. What if, you work in a project that has an admin and admin wants to see all the data about the users or products. If you exclude fields in the entities, your admin won't see those fields either. Instead, leave the entities as it is, and write dto's for each controller or for each request handler and in this dto's just list the properties you want to expose.

Then write a custom interceptor and create specific dto for ecah entity. For example in your example, you create a userDto:

```
import { Expose } from 'class-transformer';

// this is a serizalization dto
export class UserDto {
  @Expose()
  id: number;
  @Expose()
  roles: UserRoleType;
  @Expose()
  albums: Album[];
 // Basically you list what you wanna expose here
}
```

custom interceptor is a little messy:

```
import {
  UseInterceptors,
  NestInterceptor,
  ExecutionContext,
  CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { plainToClass } from 'class-transformer';

// Normally user entity goes into the interceptor and nestjs turns it into the JSON. But we we ill turn it to User DTO which will have all the serialization rules.then nest will take dto and turn it to the json and send it back as response


export class SerializerInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
    // dto is the variable. so you can use this class for different entities
    constructor(private dto:any){

    }
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, handler: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
   // you can write some code to run before request is handled
    return handler.handle().pipe(
      // data is the incoming user entity
      map((data: any) => {
        return plainToClass(this.dto, data, {
          //   this takes care of everything. this will expose things that are set in the UserDto
          excludeExtraneousValues: true,
        });
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Now you use this in the controller:

```
// See we passed UserDto. for different entities, we would just write a new dto for that entity and our custom interceptor would stay reusable
@UseInterceptors(new SerializerInterceptor(UserDto))
@Get('all')
    async findAll(
    ): Promise<UsersResponse> {
        let users = await this.userService.findAll().catch(e => { throw new   NotAcceptableException(e) })
        let rsp =new UsersResponse() 
        rsp.users = users
        return rsp
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744139/exposing-an-array-of-object-using-class-transformer can you help me in this problem.. its kind of similar

Answer (score 1):

Wow, what easy, if i know! Perfect, this solves my problem. Also your recommendation for the User Entity with the class-transformer @Exclue() decorator.

And i know that i do not need a custom UsersResponse class in this use case.
This solution was that what i was looking for, but i overjump this quite easy way

Thank you so much for your superfast answer and the problem solution.

Greetings to Berlin from Rostock :)

Here my final approach:

### Controller

```
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)
@Get('all')
async findAll(
): Promise<User> {
    return await this.userService.findAll().catch(e => { throw new NotAcceptableException(e) })
}
```

### User Entitiy

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, OneToOne, JoinColumn, OneToMany } from 'typeorm';
import { Profile } from './profile.entity';
import { Photo } from './photo.entity';
import { Album } from './album.entity';
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

export type UserRoleType = "admin" | "editor" | "ghost";

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn() id: number;
    @Column('text')
    username: string;

    @Exclude()
    @Column('text')
    password: string;

    @Column({
        type: "enum",
        enum: ["admin", "editor", "ghost"],
        default: "ghost"
    })
    roles: UserRoleType;

    @Exclude()
    @Column({ nullable: true })
    profileId: number;

    @OneToMany(type => Photo, photo => photo.user)
    photos: Photo[];

    @OneToMany(type => Album, albums => albums.user)
    albums: Album[];

    @OneToOne(type => Profile, profile => profile.user)
    @JoinColumn()
    profile: Profile;
}
```

### Response Result

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "a",
    "roles": "admin"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "bbbbbb",
    "roles": "ghost"
  }
]
```

Comment: Great, thanks for sharing your code! :-) Little side note: `return await` is always redundant unless you use it with try-catch. So I'd recommend to use try-catch instead of the chained `catch` or, alternatively, to remove the `await`.

Comment: better to decorate your main entity with Exclude decorators and then add Expose to the properties (you want to send) explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

I have alternative way for your problem.
you can remove *@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor)* from your **Controller**. Instead use *serialize* and *deserialize* function.

```
import { serialize, deserialize } from 'class-transformer';
import { User } from './users.entity';

@Get('all')
async findAll() {
  const users = serialize(await this.userService.findAll());
  return {
     status: 200,
     message: 'ok',
     users: deserialize(User, users)
  };
}
```

it's work too for single data

```
import { Param } from '@nestjs/common';    
import { serialize, deserialize } from 'class-transformer';
import { User } from './users.entity';

@Get(':id')
async findById(@Param('id') id: number) {
  const user = serialize(await this.userService.findById(id));
  return {
    status: 200,
    message: 'ok',
    user: deserialize(User, user)
  };
}
```